# performance issue with getProperties

Tags: ibm-doors

I‘m new to this so I hope I get it right.

I‘m not exactly new to writing DXL but currently have a performance issue with calling getProperties from a Layout dxl column that is supposed to display outgoing links depending on a module attribute value of type Enum of the linked module. 
The code basically works but takes extremely long to complete. Commenting out the getProperties call makes it as fast as it could be.
Yes, the call is written exactly as shown in DXL Ref manual.

Calling the attribute directly, using a module object and dot operator does not work either as it always returns the enums default value but not the actual.

Any ideas welcome...

EDIT added example code below

```
// couple of declarations snipped
string cond = "Enum selection here" // this is modified from actual code, to show the idea
string linkModName = "*"
ModuleProperties mp
for l in all(o->linkModName) do 
{
    otherVersion = targetVersion l
    otherMod = module(otherVersion)
    if (null otherMod || isDeleted otherMod) continue
    othero = target l
    if (null othero) 
    {
        load(otherVersion,false)
    }
    getProperties(otherVersion,  mp)
    sTemp = mp.myAttr
    if (sTemp == cond) continue 

// further code snipped
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I think there is/was a performance issue with module properties in some DOORS versions.

You might want to try the following, i.e. directly get the attribute from the loaded Module

```
[...]
othero = target l
Module m
if (null othero) 
{
    m = load(otherVersion,false)
} else {
    m = module othero
}
sTemp = m.myAttr
[...]
```

Caution, I did not test this snippet.

Comment: i would have liked to add a few words about why this direct method did not word for me previously, however i'm too stupid to work this comment editor

Comment: what i did wrong previously was leaving out the else clause in  
        if (null othero) 
 {
            m = load(otherVersion,false)
        }
 else m = module othero